# I have a problem with running my node.js app on my vps server

Tags: node.js, vps

I have a problem with running my node.js app on my vps server, when I run it I get an error (Error: Cannot find module 'util / types'),  but when I run it on my localhost there is no such error.
i already tried to reinstall and update node
What should i do?

Comment: Hi Bfmaar, are you sure the same version of node is installed on both machines?

Comment: Hi, in vps I have node v12.22.12 and on my PCnode  v18.2.0, I tried to change it in vps , but it didn't help